# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2) when using JSONEncoder.encode()

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, exc-bad-access

I have a (custom, linked-list based) queue that I want to deserialize when the app starts and serialize when the app stops, like so (AppDelegate.swift):

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    RequestManager.shared.serializeAndPersistQueue()
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    RequestManager.shared.deserializeStoredQueue()
}
```

The issue is during serialization when I exit the app. Here's the code that's running:

```
public func serializeAndPersistQueue() {
    do {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        let data = try encoder.encode(queue) // Bad access here
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
        }
        FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: url.path, contents: data, attributes: nil)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

As you can see, fairly straightforward. It uses the JSONEncoder to convert my `queue` to a data object, then writes that data to the file at `url`.

However, during encoder.encode() I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` every time, without fail.

Additionally, I should note that `peak` and `dequeue` operations *are* conducted on the queue from a background thread. I'm not sure if that makes a difference due to my lack of understanding surrounding GCD. Here's what that method looks like:

```
private func processRequests() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [unowned self] in
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

        while !self.queue.isEmpty {
            group.enter()
            let request = self.queue.peek()!

            self.sendRequest(request: request, completion: { [weak self] in
                _ = self?.queue.dequeue()

                semaphore.signal()
                group.leave()
            })

            semaphore.wait()
        }

        group.notify(queue: .global(), execute: { [weak self] in
            print("Ending the group")
        })
    }
}
```

Lastly, I'll note that:

- My `queue` conforms to the Codable protocol just fine––well, there are no compiler errors, at least. If its implementation beyond that matters, let me know and I'll show it.
- The crash occurs a few seconds after I exit the app, while the execution of the `processRequests` function stops immediately after

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through the code and/or set an exception breakpoint?  What exception message are you getting?

Comment: Inspired by the uncertainty in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388867/swift-jsonecoder-exc-bad-access) I just decided to refactor my `queue` implementation a bit (had that coming anyways) and the error went away.

Comment: I know this is old and resolved through refactor, but I just ran across a similar problem when using `Codable` with `RawRepresentable`.  [Swift Forum](https://forums.swift.org/t/rawrepresentable-conformance-leads-to-crash/51912) provides a solution and explanation. Not sure if that was your issue above.